# Azure WebJob has status "Never finished" in WebJobs Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have long running web job in AppService (around 1h).
AppService has "Always on" turned on.

It is initialized with:

```
var host = new JobHost(config);
host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("SyncUsers"));
host.Start();
```

Actual methods SyncUsers wrapped with attributes:

```
[Timeout("00:59:00", ThrowOnTimeout = true)]
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
```

Schedule is set with settings file settings.job:

```
{
  "is_singleton": true,
  "schedule": "0 0 */4 * * *"
}
```

Main issue is that in WebJobs Dashboard I see status "Never finished" in 90% of cases (or failed with exception - OK situation). Running time for such jobs is different: from 5 min to 30 mins. Logs just stopped at some moment without any exception or detailed message.

Another thing is that I can see that multiple jobs are running in the same time. So looks like singleton and schedule don't work (since job should run every 4h).
Also some jobs that have this status, displayed without running time, like this: "1 hour ago ( running time)" and I am not able to see logs or download them.

Anybody had such experience?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to run an executable that never ends as a triggered WebJob, which has no chance of working. You need to either:

1. Use a continuous WebJob and rely on the WebJobs SDK for your timer
2. Use a plain console app deployed as a Scheduled WebJob. No need to use the SDK here. Just do what you need to do from your Main() and let it end.

I'd suggest #2 unless you have a specific need to use the WebJobs SDK.

Comment: The job has continuous type, so for now I am already using #1

Comment: But you're trying to use a schedule in settings.job and that's only meaningful with triggered jobs. See [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#scheduling-a-triggered-webjob). Continuous jobs run forever, so there is no such thing as a schedule. #1 is about using a TimerTrigger in the SDK. But I highly suggest that you use #2, which is far simpler and may help clear your confusion.

Comment: Thank you! Will have a look.